# jdbc doesn't insert the data after the first run in Overwrite mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write the data to MySQL from my Spark job. While writing the data to the MySQL table, spark does nothing when the table is already present in the MySQL DB. If I drop the table and then run my job, the table is created and the data is inserted as expected. However, when I re-run the job, the data is not being inserted. Also, I get no spark error message on the console.

```
df=spark.read.parquet("xxx/xxx/xxx")

df.write.jdbc(url=connection_str,table="employee",  mode="overwrite" , properties={"driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"})
```

Comment: What is error/exception you get ?

Comment: I am not getting any exception/error. I just see :

WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

I am not sure what is happening.